# Is HyperJaxb3 still maintained?

Tags: jpa, jaxb, xsd, eclipselink, hyperjaxb

I think this question should be fairly simple. I'm looking forward to persisting JAXB generated classes from a schema into a database via JPA annotations.

I came across Hyperjaxb3 but I noticed that most of the project's activity stopped in 2011.

So is this project being maintained still?

Are there any other alternative frameworks that can offer JAXB persistence via JPA? I found about EclipseLink but I seems to me that it is a much more general purpose tool.

Thanks!

Comment: DataNucleus has an XML plugin that makes use of the JAXB reference implementation for providing JPA/JDO persistence of objects to XML

Comment: Thank you. However, I think the workflow I'm going after is different, like so: `XSD -> (JAXB + JPA annotations) -> Java Classes -> JPA -> Database`. Is this possible to do with DataNucleus as well? Thanks again!

Comment: No, DataNucleus does the second half of that, from the Java classes with annotations, through persistence, to the datastore.

Comment: EclipseLink offers JPA and JAXB implementations, but does not support generating JPA annotated models from an XML Schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best bet is email their users mailing list (users@hyperjaxb3.java.net) with this question.  Poking around there site (https://java.net/projects/hyperjaxb3) things seem pretty quiet..

Comment: Indeed. It's pretty strange to me though that not a lot of people are interested in tackling this particular problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @datSilencer - I lead the JAXB implementation in EclipseLink.  Our focus has always been on mapping JPA entities to XML, rather than generating entities from XML schema.

Comment: Ah, my bad :P. Yes I was referring to the whole situation about generating JPA annotated classes from a schema. So it seems that for now, there isn't something like Hyperjaxb3 out there. Strange. Thanks again!